# Three and more simultaneous message-handling functions are not working (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, multithreading, telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a telegram bot, that has to process several messages at the same time. After the message handling function of this bot catches the message, it has to run for several hours (sending timed HTTP requests, processing data, etc).
The thing is, if I try to send three or more messages to my bot, that involve running this function, only two first messages are processed as expected, and the following ones are ignored.

Here is a part of my code:

```
import os, time
import telebot

import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', filemode='w')


bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.getenv('TG_BOT_TOKEN'))

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'I`m working on your message!')
    logging.info(f'Working on message {message.text}')
    
    while True:
        # do something with message.text
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            bot.send_message(chat_id='DM with me', text='The bot just died! Please resend the messages!')
            time.sleep(5)
```

Now suppose I send three messages to the bot via Telegram: **MESSAGE1**, **MESSAGE2**, **MESSAGE3**.
This is how my `example.log` would look like:

```
2023-03-25 21:44:00,668 DEBUG:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org:443
2023-03-25 21:44:00,831 DEBUG:https://api.telegram.org:443 "GET /bot[TOKEN]/getMe HTTP/1.1" 200 211
2023-03-25 21:44:00,833 DEBUG:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org:443
2023-03-25 21:44:08,266 DEBUG:https://api.telegram.org:443 "GET /bot[TOKEN]/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 517
2023-03-25 21:44:08,270 DEBUG:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org:443
2023-03-25 21:44:08,462 DEBUG:https://api.telegram.org:443 "POST /bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage?chat_id=[DM with me]&text=I%60m+working+on+your+message%21 HTTP/1.1" 200 321
2023-03-25 21:44:08,688 INFO:Working on message MESSAGE1
```

and pretty much the same set of logs for **MESSAGE2**. But nothing appears if I send **MESSAGE3**, neither the POST request, nor the INFO message from the logging library, from which I figured out that the third instance of the function didn't even start running.

**QUESTION**: What am I doing wrong?